# Is it possible to write DirectShow filters in C# (not in c\c++)?

Tags: c#, filter, directshow

Is it possible to write DirectShow filters in C# (not in c\c++)?

I mean not only to create source filters but renderers or compressors etc?

Answer (score 4):

[Maxim Kartavenkov](http://www.codeproject.com/Members/Maxim-Kartavenkov) has written a lot of useful DirectShow articles on [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=1301414). Take a look at this article: [Pure .NET DirectShow Filters in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421167/Pure-NET-DirectShow-Filters-in-Csharp). It not only contains source filters, but also transform filters, renderers, encoders etc.

The code in his articles are not based on the directshow.net library, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. You can use the [DirectShow.net Lib](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html) to help bridge the gap.

They even have a sample, if you look down the page you will see the GSSF sample description:

> GSSF – The Generic Sample Source
>   Filter – A way to implement a source
>   filter in c#. If you have samples (for
>   example video frames from bitmap
>   files) that you want to use as a
>   source in a graph, this filter will
>   show you how.

Comment: And is there any way to create not only source filters but for example renderers or compressorsetc?

Answer (score 3):

You can, but it can be difficult unless you know DirectShow and .NET native interop pretty well.  Even then it can be a little uphill.

Here is an example of it being done:  http://www.sichbo.ca/Free_Code/100_C_Sharp_directshow_filters

Answer (score 1):

I think implementing a complete DirectShow-Filter in C# is a bad idea. The C++ DirectShowBaseClasses are so helpful. To re-implement these will result in a complete mess.

If you want to implement a decoder/encoder or some audio/video-effect then you can create a DMO (maybe in C# but C++ would be better). If you need a Source-Filter, take the Ball-Sample and modify it. If you need other types of filters, then take a look at the samples (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468(v=vs.85).aspx) and modify one.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can export you .NET classes as COM. TO use DShow interfaces, simply link to CM objects from your .NET projects. Anyway, writing DShow filters in .NET without some support of libraries like BaseClasses for C++ could be challenging.